# GluonCV - Use GPU for inference in object detection

Tags: python, object-detection, mxnet

I'm using GluonCV for object detection, on Ubuntu 18.04 and with Python.
I re-trained the *ssd_512_resnet50_v1_custom* model on a custom dataset, and I wanted to test the inference FPS on a server with a GeForce RTX 2080 Ti GPU (works fine on my computer's CPU).

So, I'm running

```py
def main():

    try:
        a = mx.nd.zeros((1,), ctx=mx.gpu(1))
        ctx = [mx.gpu(1)]
    except:
        ctx = [mx.cpu()]

    # -------------------------
    # Load model
    # -------------------------
    classes = ['Guitar', 'face']
    net = model_zoo.get_model('ssd_512_resnet50_v1_custom', ctx=ctx, classes=classes, pretrained_base=False)
    net.load_parameters('saved_weights/test_000/ep_30.params')

    # Load the webcam handler
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video/video_01.mp4")

    count_frame = 0

    loading_frame_FPSs = np.zeros(844)
    pre_processing_FPSs = np.zeros(844)
    inference_FPSs = np.zeros(844)
    total_FPSs = np.zeros(844)

    while(True):
        print(f"Frame: {count_frame}")

        total_t_frame = 0

        #######
        start_t = time.time()
        #######
        # Load frame from the camera
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        #######
        stop_t = time.time()
        total_t_frame += (stop_t - start_t)
        FPS = 1/(stop_t-start_t)
        loading_frame_FPSs[count_frame] = FPS
        print(f"\tloading frame time = {(stop_t-start_t)} -> FPS = {FPS}")
        #######

        if (cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q')) or (ret == False):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            cap.release()
            print("Done!!!")
            break

        #######
        start_t = time.time()
        #######
        # Image pre-processing
        frame = mx.nd.array(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)).astype('uint8')
        rgb_nd, frame = gcv.data.transforms.presets.ssd.transform_test(frame, short=512, max_size=700)
        #######
        stop_t = time.time()
        total_t_frame += (stop_t - start_t)
        FPS = 1/(stop_t-start_t)
        pre_processing_FPSs[count_frame] = FPS
        print(f"\timage pre-processing time = {(stop_t-start_t)} -> FPS = {FPS}")
        #######

        #######
        start_t = time.time()
        #######
        # Run frame through network
        class_IDs, scores, bounding_boxes = net(rgb_nd)
        #######
        stop_t = time.time()
        total_t_frame += (stop_t - start_t)
        FPS = 1/(stop_t-start_t)
        inference_FPSs[count_frame] = FPS
        print(f"\tinference time = {(stop_t-start_t)} -> FPS = {1/(stop_t-start_t)}")
        #######

        print(f"\tTotal frame FPS = {1/total_t_frame}")
        total_FPSs[count_frame] = 1/total_t_frame


        count_frame += 1


    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cap.release()


    print(f"Average FPS for:")
    print(f"\tloading frame: {np.average(loading_frame_FPSs)}")
    print(f"\tpre-processingg frame: {np.average(pre_processing_FPSs)}")
    print(f"\tinference frame: {np.average(inference_FPSs)}")
    print(f"\ttotal process: {np.average(total_FPSs)}")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So, basically I’m measuring the time required for every inference step (loading frame, resizing, inference), and calculating the FPS for each of these steps and in total.

Looking at the output:

```
Average FPS for:
loading frame: 813.3313447171636
pre-processingg frame: 10.488629638752457
inference frame: 101.50787170217922
total process: 9.300166489874748
```

it seems that the bottleneck is mostly given by the pre-processing of the images.
When checking the output of nvidia-smi, I got:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.56       Driver Version: 418.56       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 208...  Off  | 00000000:18:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 36%   63C    P0    79W / 250W |     10MiB / 10989MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce RTX 208...  Off  | 00000000:3B:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 37%   65C    P2    84W / 250W |    715MiB / 10989MiB |      5%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  GeForce RTX 208...  Off  | 00000000:86:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 37%   64C    P0    70W / 250W |     10MiB / 10989MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  GeForce RTX 208...  Off  | 00000000:AF:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 37%   62C    P2   116W / 250W |   2401MiB / 10989MiB |     47%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    1      2955      C   python                                       705MiB |
|    3     15558      C   python                                      2389MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

which I guess is reasonable, since for inference I’m using just one image at a time, so I don’t expect the GPU usage to be as high as it is during training.

At this point, however, there are a couple of things I’m not sure about:

1. when reading about the average FPS of SSD models, they’re usually mentioned to be in the range of 25-30 FPS. How do I get to those values? Is it all about image pre-processing?
2. I tried to modify the block

```
try:
    a = mx.nd.zeros((1,), ctx=mx.gpu(1))
    ctx = [mx.gpu(1)]
except:
    ctx = [mx.cpu()]
```

with simply:

```
ctx = mx.gpu(1)
```

but it seems that this way the process is running on CPU (not even those 715 MB are occupied on GPU). Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn’t properly loading images on the GPU, I had to add a line before running inference:

```
rgb_nd = rgb_nd.as_in_context(ctx)
class_IDs, scores, bounding_boxes = net(rgb_nd)
```

which increased the GPU memory usage, and solved the problem with the initial context initialization.

Also, when evaluating the inference speed I had to use a block to wait for the results to be actually available, so now I'm getting inference frame rate in the range of 20 FPS as expected:

```
    class_IDs, scores, bounding_boxes = net(rgb_nd)
    if isinstance(class_IDs, mx.ndarray.ndarray.NDArray):
        class_IDs.wait_to_read()
    if isinstance(scores, mx.ndarray.ndarray.NDArray):
        scores.wait_to_read()
    if isinstance(bounding_boxes, mx.ndarray.ndarray.NDArray):
        bounding_boxes.wait_to_read()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `ctx = mx.gpu(0)` or `ctx = mx.gpu()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the script at the following page? Does it perform the same? Maybe use your model and try using the same image pre-processing approach

https://github.com/dmlc/gluon-cv/blob/master/scripts/detection/demo_webcam_run.py